# Can we get B2C user information via server push?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, signalr, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure and want to notify ReactApp via server push only when I update a user's information in B2C.
Therefore, we are considering using azure functions and signalR. Is it possible to send information from the server side (B2C) to the screen only when the B2C information is updated?
thank you!!!